# Extending with :gen-class a class that exposes its naked fields

Tags: clojure, gen-class

Suppose there is a Java class that doesn't provide getters and setters for all its fields, and I have to extend it with `:gen-class` and fiddle with them.

How do I access the superclass fields?

The quickest (and perhaps cleanest...) solution that comes to my mind right now is to create a java class that extends my super class, and extend it instead, but I was wondering if there is an alternative that sounds more direct.

Thanks!

Comment: Are those fields public, protected, package private, or private?

Comment: Assume "public" for simplicity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods in generated classes can access base class fields with the help of the `:exposes` option of `gen-class`. `:exposes` expects a map where keys are symbols matching base class field names; values are also maps like `{:get getterName, :set setterName}`. Clojure generates those getter and setter methods automatically. They can be used to read and modify base class fields. This is documented in the [docstring](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/gen-class) for `gen-class`.

This approach works for public and protected fields. It does not work for private fields.

Assuming the Java base class like this:

```
package fields;

class Base {
    public String baseField = "base";
}
```

The Clojure code to generate a subclass would be:

```
(ns fields.core
  (:gen-class
   :extends fields.Base
   :methods [[bar [] String]
             [baz [String] Object]]
   :exposes { baseField { :get getField :set setField }}))

(defn -bar [this]
  (str (.getField this) "-sub"))

(defn -baz [this val]
  (.setField this val)
  this)

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println (.. (fields.core.) (bar)))
  (println (.. (fields.core.) (baz "new-base") (bar))))
```

Assuming all this is AOT compiled and ran, the output is:

```
base-sub
new-base-sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the great (and very detailed) answer! PS: it's just me, or the clojure docstrings need some indenting/reformatting? :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having a bit of trouble understanding all of the details and decided to try out a minimal version. Here is a file listing:

```
> d **/*.{clj,java}
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan 501 Jun 29 17:11 project.clj
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan 431 Jun 29 17:10 src/demo/core.clj
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan  63 Jun 29 16:57 src-java/jpak/Base.java
```

Here is the `project.clj`

```
(defproject demo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "demo code"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [
    [org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
    [tupelo "0.9.55"]
  ]
  :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [ [org.clojure/test.check "0.9.0"] ] }
             :uberjar {:aot :all} }
  :java-source-paths ["src-java"]
  :aot [ demo.core ]
  :main ^:skip-aot demo.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  jvm-opts ["-Xms500m" "-Xmx500m" ]
)
```

and the Java class:

```
package jpak;
public class Base {
  public long answer = 41;
}
```

and our Clojure code:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:gen-class
   :extends jpak.Base
   :exposes {answer {:get getans :set setans}}
 ))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [sub-obj    (demo.core.) ; default name of subclass
        old-answer (.getans sub-obj)
        >>         (.setans sub-obj (inc old-answer))
        new-answer (.getans sub-obj)  ]
    (println "old answer = " old-answer)
    (println "new answer = " new-answer)
  ))
```

We can run using `lein run` to get:

```
> lein run  
old answer =  41
new answer =  42
```

---

**Version 2**

The above continues to work if the Java variable `answer` is protected, but fails if it is either `private` or "package protected" (no qualifier). This makes sense since our subclass is in a different package.

Also, it is a little cleaner if I give the subclass a name different than the default value, which is the clojure namespace name "demo.core":

```
(ns demo.core
  (:gen-class
   :name demo.Sub
   :extends jpak.Base
   :exposes {answer {:get getans :set setans}}
 ))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [sub-obj    (demo.Sub.) ; new name of subclass
        old-answer (.getans sub-obj)
        >>         (.setans sub-obj (inc old-answer))
        new-answer (.getans sub-obj)
  ]
    (println "old answer = " old-answer)
    (println "new answer = " new-answer)
  ))
```

---

**Version 3: Access `private` member values**

In Java, a subclass cannot normally see private member variables of a superclass; "package protected" members from a different package are also restricted. Here is the pesky Java class:

```
package jpak;
public class Base {
  private long answer = 41;
}
```

However, Java has a well-known ability to override `private` access restrictions, and you don't even need a subclass!  All you need to do is use reflection.  Here is the clojure version:

```
(ns demo.break
  (:import [jpak Base]))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [base-obj   (Base.)
        class-obj  (.getClass base-obj)
        ans-field  (.getDeclaredField class-obj "answer")
        >>         (.setAccessible ans-field true)
        old-answer (.get ans-field base-obj)
        >>         (.set ans-field base-obj 42)
        new-answer (.get ans-field base-obj)
  ]
    (println "old answer = " old-answer)
    (println "new answer = " new-answer)))

> lein run -m demo.break
old answer =  41
new answer =  42
```

[See the docs for AccessibleObject here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html).  Note that `Field` & `Method`, which are the classes returned during reflection, are both included.